# Optimal way to variable aliasing in C++

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, assembly

I want to learn variable aliasing in C++ for make much code lesser than before without pay any cost (Zero Cost), for I can better describe my purpose, please see below details

I have a structure like below

```cpp
struct Info
{
    size_t d1;
    size_t d2;
    size_t d3;
    size_t d4;
};
```

I use this struct in another class. (that call `LargeName` class) like below

```cpp
class LargeName
{
public:
// … many fields and methods
    Info get_large_name_info() const
    {
        return info;
    }

private:
    Info info;
}
```

In this scenario if I want to use info fields from `LargeName` instant in external function, I have to something like below

```cpp
void foo(LargeName large_name)
{
  large_name.get_large_name_info().d1;
  large_name.get_large_name_info().d2;
  large_name.get_large_name_info().d3;
  large_name.get_large_name_info().d4;
}
```

As you can see in above example if my class name and getter access name of info is too long, I have to write very character to use d1 to d4. But I want to avoid them. so for example I can write below code to prevent that

```cpp
void foo(LargeName large_name)
{
  const Info& info = large_name.get_large_name_info();
  info.d1;
  info.d2;
  info.d3;
  info.d4;
}
```

As you can see my code is little cleaner and very shorter than before. (I called `info` is **alias variable** for `large_name.get_large_name_info()`) But the problem is I have not sure to compiler generate equal code for new version of my code that same as before.

I think second foo implementation my pay reference and dereferencing cost for using info variable.

I have two question:

**First question is how to variable aliasing in C++ without pay any cost?**

**Note:** The assembly version of two `foo` function is different. I check with GCC version 5.4.0 with `-std=c++11 -O3 -S` switch .

**Second question is** why compiler generate different code for those `foo` method? on which situation these two codes (first `foo` and second `foo`) does not behave same exactly (I want to learn why compiler generate different code?) ? ( I think if two code is same exactly, then assembly generated must be same )

-------------------- APPENDIX -------------------

A full example:

Source code:

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>

#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    int id;
    std::array<size_t, 4> data;
    float prec;
};

class User
{
public:
    A get_a() const
    {
        return a;
    }

private:
    A a;
};

int main()
{
    User user;

    // scenario 1
#ifdef SC1
    cout << "A id: " << user.get_a().id << endl;
    cout << "A prec: " << user.get_a().prec << endl;
    cout << "A data: ";
    cout << user.get_a().data[0];
    cout << user.get_a().data[1];
    cout << user.get_a().data[2];
    cout << user.get_a().data[3];
    cout << endl;
#endif
    // scenario 2
#ifdef SC2
    const A& a = user.get_a();
    cout << "A id: " << a.id << endl;
    cout << "A prec: " << a.prec << endl;
    cout << "A data: ";
    cout << a.data[0];
    cout << a.data[1];
    cout << a.data[2];
    cout << a.data[3];
    cout << endl;
#endif

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

compile with `g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -D=SC1 -S main.cpp`

scenario 1:

```
    .file   "main.cpp"
    .section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.LC0:
    .string "A id: "
.LC1:
    .string "A prec: "
.LC2:
    .string "A data: "
    .section    .text.unlikely,"ax",@progbits
.LCOLDB3:
    .section    .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
.LHOTB3:
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB1495:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbx
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 3, -16
    movl    $6, %edx
    movl    $.LC0, %esi
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
    subq    $80, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 96
    movl    16(%rsp), %ebx
    movq    %fs:40, %rax
    movq    %rax, 72(%rsp)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    call    _ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_l
    movl    %ebx, %esi
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
    call    _ZNSolsEi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
    movss   56(%rsp), %xmm1
    movl    $8, %edx
    movl    $.LC1, %esi
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
    movss   %xmm1, 12(%rsp)
    call    _ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_l
    pxor    %xmm0, %xmm0
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
    cvtss2sd    12(%rsp), %xmm0
    call    _ZNSo9_M_insertIdEERSoT_
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
    movl    $.LC2, %esi
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
    call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc
    movq    24(%rsp), %rsi
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
    call    _ZNSo9_M_insertImEERSoT_
    movq    32(%rsp), %rsi
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
    call    _ZNSo9_M_insertImEERSoT_
    movq    40(%rsp), %rsi
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
    call    _ZNSo9_M_insertImEERSoT_
    movq    48(%rsp), %rsi
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
    call    _ZNSo9_M_insertImEERSoT_
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
    call    _ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
    movq    72(%rsp), %rcx
    xorq    %fs:40, %rcx
    jne .L5
    addq    $80, %rsp
    .cfi_remember_state
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popq    %rbx
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    ret
.L5:
    .cfi_restore_state
    call    __stack_chk_fail
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1495:
    .size   main, .-main
    .section    .text.unlikely
.LCOLDE3:
    .section    .text.startup
.LHOTE3:
    .section    .text.unlikely
.LCOLDB4:
    .section    .text.startup
.LHOTB4:
    .p2align 4,,15
    .type   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main, @function
_GLOBAL__sub_I_main:
.LFB1689:
    .cfi_startproc
    subq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    movl    $_ZStL8__ioinit, %edi
    call    _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
    movl    $__dso_handle, %edx
    movl    $_ZStL8__ioinit, %esi
    movl    $_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev, %edi
    addq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    jmp __cxa_atexit
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1689:
    .size   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main, .-_GLOBAL__sub_I_main
    .section    .text.unlikely
.LCOLDE4:
    .section    .text.startup
.LHOTE4:
    .section    .init_array,"aw"
    .align 8
    .quad   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main
    .local  _ZStL8__ioinit
    .comm   _ZStL8__ioinit,1,1
    .hidden __dso_handle
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 5.4.0 20160609"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

compile with `g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -D=SC2 -S main.cpp`

Scenario 2:

```
    .file   "main.cpp"
    .section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.LC0:
    .string "A id: "
.LC1:
    .string "A prec: "
.LC2:
    .string "A data: "
    .section    .text.unlikely,"ax",@progbits
.LCOLDB3:
    .section    .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
.LHOTB3:
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB1495:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %r14
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 14, -16
    pushq   %r13
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 24
    .cfi_offset 13, -24
    movl    $6, %edx
    pushq   %r12
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
    .cfi_offset 12, -32
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 40
    .cfi_offset 6, -40
    movl    $.LC0, %esi
    pushq   %rbx
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 48
    .cfi_offset 3, -48
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
    subq    $80, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 128
    movl    16(%rsp), %r14d
    movss   56(%rsp), %xmm1
    movss   %xmm1, 12(%rsp)
    movq    24(%rsp), %r13
    movq    32(%rsp), %r12
    movq    %fs:40, %rax
    movq    %rax, 72(%rsp)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movq    40(%rsp), %rbp
    movq    48(%rsp), %rbx
    call    _ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_l
    movl    %r14d, %esi
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
    call    _ZNSolsEi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
    movl    $8, %edx
    movl    $.LC1, %esi
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
    call    _ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_l
    pxor    %xmm0, %xmm0
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
    cvtss2sd    12(%rsp), %xmm0
    call    _ZNSo9_M_insertIdEERSoT_
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
    movl    $.LC2, %esi
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
    call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc
    movq    %r13, %rsi
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
    call    _ZNSo9_M_insertImEERSoT_
    movq    %r12, %rsi
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
    call    _ZNSo9_M_insertImEERSoT_
    movq    %rbp, %rsi
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
    call    _ZNSo9_M_insertImEERSoT_
    movq    %rbx, %rsi
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
    call    _ZNSo9_M_insertImEERSoT_
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
    call    _ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
    movq    72(%rsp), %rcx
    xorq    %fs:40, %rcx
    jne .L5
    addq    $80, %rsp
    .cfi_remember_state
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 48
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popq    %rbx
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 40
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
    popq    %r12
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 24
    popq    %r13
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    popq    %r14
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    ret
.L5:
    .cfi_restore_state
    call    __stack_chk_fail
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1495:
    .size   main, .-main
    .section    .text.unlikely
.LCOLDE3:
    .section    .text.startup
.LHOTE3:
    .section    .text.unlikely
.LCOLDB4:
    .section    .text.startup
.LHOTB4:
    .p2align 4,,15
    .type   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main, @function
_GLOBAL__sub_I_main:
.LFB1689:
    .cfi_startproc
    subq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    movl    $_ZStL8__ioinit, %edi
    call    _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
    movl    $__dso_handle, %edx
    movl    $_ZStL8__ioinit, %esi
    movl    $_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev, %edi
    addq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    jmp __cxa_atexit
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1689:
    .size   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main, .-_GLOBAL__sub_I_main
    .section    .text.unlikely
.LCOLDE4:
    .section    .text.startup
.LHOTE4:
    .section    .init_array,"aw"
    .align 8
    .quad   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main
    .local  _ZStL8__ioinit
    .comm   _ZStL8__ioinit,1,1
    .hidden __dso_handle
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 5.4.0 20160609"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

And diff is:

```
19c19
<   pushq   %rbx
---
>   pushq   %r14
21c21,24
<   .cfi_offset 3, -16
---
>   .cfi_offset 14, -16
>   pushq   %r13
>   .cfi_def_cfa_offset 24
>   .cfi_offset 13, -24
22a26,31
>   pushq   %r12
>   .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
>   .cfi_offset 12, -32
>   pushq   %rbp
>   .cfi_def_cfa_offset 40
>   .cfi_offset 6, -40
23a33,35
>   pushq   %rbx
>   .cfi_def_cfa_offset 48
>   .cfi_offset 3, -48
26,27c38,43
<   .cfi_def_cfa_offset 96
<   movl    16(%rsp), %ebx
---
>   .cfi_def_cfa_offset 128
>   movl    16(%rsp), %r14d
>   movss   56(%rsp), %xmm1
>   movss   %xmm1, 12(%rsp)
>   movq    24(%rsp), %r13
>   movq    32(%rsp), %r12
30a47,48
>   movq    40(%rsp), %rbp
>   movq    48(%rsp), %rbx
32c50
<   movl    %ebx, %esi
---
>   movl    %r14d, %esi
37d54
<   movss   56(%rsp), %xmm1
41d57
<   movss   %xmm1, 12(%rsp)
52c68
<   movq    24(%rsp), %rsi
---
>   movq    %r13, %rsi
55c71
<   movq    32(%rsp), %rsi
---
>   movq    %r12, %rsi
58c74
<   movq    40(%rsp), %rsi
---
>   movq    %rbp, %rsi
61c77
<   movq    48(%rsp), %rsi
---
>   movq    %rbx, %rsi
71c87
<   .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
---
>   .cfi_def_cfa_offset 48
73a90,97
>   .cfi_def_cfa_offset 40
>   popq    %rbp
>   .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
>   popq    %r12
>   .cfi_def_cfa_offset 24
>   popq    %r13
>   .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
>   popq    %r14
```

Comment: Why don't you compile both versions on godbolt and see if there's any difference in assembly? That's a good place to start.

Comment: @cigien the problem is two version is different assembly

Comment: Ok, then profile the 2 versions, and see if there is a measurable speed difference.

Comment: I want to found best way for variable aliasing, my trick is just simple example that I hope to behave like variable aliasing for compiler, but it seems to not correct.

Comment: @cigien I cannot check every program and measure speed, I want to find a way to declare variable alias that compiler guarantee to doesn't generate any extra assembly (does pay any extra cost)

Comment: No difference here - https://godbolt.org/z/XBnZaG

Comment: @PeterCordes oh you correct I correct it, thanks :)

Comment: @dewaffled I test with my computer not with Godbolt, but I don't any confidence to my test is correct, but are you sure this technique generate same assembly in all situation?

Comment: @sorosh_sabz The compiler can do whatever it wants. You never have a guarantee that the generated code is the same. That being said, with optimizations turned on, and when the implementation of `get_large_name_info` is known by the compiler not to have any side effects, then this is safe.
This relies on the fact that `get_large_name_info` doesn't actually do anything but return a member. This is easy for the compiler to optimize out.

Comment: @ThomasJager you right, but some times, some technique always (near always ;) ) get same result and some other concept like copy elision in C++ is standard behavior that compiler must behave like that. my question is: is there any technique or pattern exist aliasing variable in C++ that has not cost near always?

Comment: this is exactly the type of micro-optimization you definitely should not worry about. Forget about performance here and just write clean readable code. Even if there is a difference between them, it wouldn't be more than a few assembly instructions and such a small difference will be completely swallowed by noise in the system.

Comment: @bolov maybe you correct, but I want to know it about that way very accurate and detailed. also I think in performance critical code with many many variable aliasing, if referencing and dereferencing is happened, I think performance may be downgrading like using pointer when we can don't use it. :)

Comment: @dewaffled I add full example to explain more details, thanks for help me

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is logical, and clean, and neat.

As for performance, you can only really find this out by *measuring it* and *reading the assembly* on your particular machine with your particular build settings. But I'd be very surprised if you paid *any* "cost" here. Compilers are clever; they don't force you into a pointer dereference if they don't need to. Besides, references *aren't* just "pointers in disguise", they symbolise a new name for an existing piece of data, and your compiler understands what you're trying to do with that.

If anything, you *may* gain from skipping some unnecessary `Info` copy constructions and calls to `get_large_name_info()`.

Even if there were some small performance hit for some reason, unless you've put this code into a tight loop, I imagine the improved legibility of the code is *well* worth the cost of a tiny thing like a pointer dereference.

In fact, since you're copying the `Info`, the whole reference bit is a completely unnecessary distraction; you're just extending the lifetime of a local temporary anyway. Much simpler, but just the same:

```
const Info info = large_name.get_large_name_info();
```

Now you don't even have a reference to worry about.

Finally, there doesn't seem to be any reason to return that `Info` by value. Absent "optimisations" and the like, this is just logically unnecessary. If you return the original member as `const Info&` instead, then the entire discussion is moot, and the compiler will still probably not form a pointer and some dereference operations, because it's clever and knows that it doesn't need to.

**tl;dr: probably don't worry about it**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216267/discussion-on-answer-by-asteroids-with-wings-optimal-way-to-variable-aliasing-in).

Answer (score 1):

### "aliasing" and your code design

First thing's first: Your `get_large_name_info()` makes a *copy* of the `info` field. While, in practice, the copying may be optimized away, it's probably not what you want to do; rather, it's more common to return a constant lvalue reference (in your case, `const Info&`

Secondly, you wrote:

> I called info is alias variable for `large_name.get_large_name_info()`

that term is confusing. The typical use of the word "aliasing" w.r.t. C and C++ is for when mutlitple pointers (or perhaps references) point to overlapping areas in memory. if your method returned a `const&`, then you could say you've got a sort of an alias *for the member `info` of class `LargeName`.*

Finally, why not use the field name as the getter name, instead?

This would give you:

```
class LargeName {
public:
// … many fields and methods
    const Info& info() const { return info_; }

private:
    Info info_;
}
```

and you would write, say:

```
void foo(LargeName bar) {
  bar.info().d1;
  bar.info().d2;
  bar.info().d3;
  bar.info().d4;
}
```

it's true that you can shorten this further, but: if you just a variable named `info` in `foo()`, people might not know which `info` that is.

---

PS - Maybe your `Info` class should have a size_t d[4] rather than four fields? That shortens some thing as well (at the cost of no distinct identifiers).

### The supposedly different code for the different methods

I can't reproduce this. With GCC 10.1, I [get the same code for both scenarios in your appendix](https://godbolt.org/z/tnrwxY).

Comment: Since you're discussing the C++ meaning of aliasing, perhaps that would be a good time to mention why the OP gets different asm: making a local copy of `info` before some non-inline function calls, vs. re-accessing the original possibly-globally-reachable object every time.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but did you can explain, why compiler generate different code? Your description about getter and... Maybe is correct, but it is our code style and out of scope of this question, my exactly question is, what is optimal way for creation variable shortcut ( variable aliasing)?

Comment: @sorosh_sabz: 1. I can't reproduce the differences. Perhaps you're using an older version of GCC? See my edit. 2. "Optimality" is mostly meaningless in this context, since you're not doing any intensive computational work, plus - the compiler can theoretically get rid of most of your code and arrange things how it sees fit.

Comment: The OP's gcc output does include the GCC 5.4 version string.  It does reproduce with that older GCC, which apparently didn't do so well with **reading the uninitialized `User user` object on the stack (which is Undefined Behaviour)**.  Changing the declaration to initialize as well, `User user {};`, we get identical code from both: https://godbolt.org/z/3xT7w9.  @sorosh_sabz.  Don't forget to use `-Wall` when playing with compilers, you want warnings in case you did something silly you didn't intend (e.g. UB).

Comment: @PeterCordes: Fair warning, but I only created that link to show what I get with OP's command-line.